Periodically resetting the internal state of a 3rd party DLL
In my .NET 8 Windows service I import a 3rd party DLL. Over time the service becomes sluggish (e.g. over 3-4 days of heavy use), and I want to eliminate this DLL as the cause (e.g. perhaps it has some internal counters or is holding onto something etc.).
What I would like to do is reset the DLL back to the state it was when the application started. Is there any way to do this?
This DLL is added to my project as an assembly, and from there I can interact with it directly from .NET.
A restart of the service does solve the problem, and this is just one avenue I am investigating.

Is this a native or managed DLL? For managed DLLs you should be able to use a memory profiler to confirm that the dll is the culprit. A performance profiler might also be useful so see what is taking time.

It hugely depends on the actual DLL. If it is a managed one - then you can do a lot of Voodoo with reflection, but this will require a lot of understanding of inner workings of the DLL. Arguably easier approach would be to move DLL usage "out-of-process" and restarting it in this way, i.e. you start a process which runs the DLL and use some RPC to communicate with it (CLI, memory-mapped files, named pipes, TCP, HTTP, etc.) and restart that process from time to time. Or just set up scheduled restarts of the service.

Hi, I'm pretty sure it’s a native DLL, and I can’t look inside it or anything like that. I have been running performance profiles and they don’t give any detail of what’s going on inside it.

I like the idea of shifting the DLL out of process, that is probably worth some investigation, - thanks!
